# Find last text node in DOM

Tags: php, dom, text

I have some html string:

$string - a string taken from user.

```
$dom = new DomDocument;
$dom ->preserveWhiteSpace = false;
$dom ->loadHTML('<?xml encoding="UTF-8">'.$string);
```

How can I find a last text node in DOM tree using PHP? What I want to do is to add some extra chars at the end of to finded string. Next I'll replace old text node with the new string.

Answer (score 2):

Assuming

```
$xml = <<< XML
<a>
    First Text Node
    <b>foo</b>
    Another Text Node
    <c>bar</c>
    Not the last Text Node
    <empty/>
</a>
XML;
```

Using this code:

```
$dom = new DOMDocument;
$dom->loadXml($xml);
$xp = new DOMXPath($dom);
$textNodes = $xp->query('//text()');
$lastTextNode = $textNodes->item($textNodes->length - 1);
$lastTextNode->nodeValue .= 'some stuff appended to the end';
echo $dom->saveXml();
```

will output:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<a>
    First Text Node
    <b>foo</b>
    Another Text Node
    <c>bar</c>
    Not the last Text Node
    <empty/>
some stuff appended to the end</a>
```

If this is not what you consider the last node, please clarify the question.